# Difference between add() & replace() with Fragment's lifecycle

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

My program has 6 fragments: Fragment1, Fragment2,....->Fragment6.

I use the add() and replace() statement to switch between the fragment and track their lifecycle.

Fragment1 **add** Fragment2 **add** Fragment3 **add** Fragment4 **add** Fragment5 **replace** Fragment6

The log-cat to shown their lifecycle (i have some printf-points in onCreate, onCreateView, onDestroyView, onDestroy for tracking)

---

**Tag** __*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__ ***Text***

Fragment1_***_*__*_*___**_onCreate

Fragment1_***_*__*_*___**_onCreateView

Fragment1_***_*__*_*___**_add Fragment2

Fragment2_***_*__*_*___**_onCreate

Fragment2_***_*__*_*___**_onCreateView

Fragment2_***_*__*_*___**_add Fragment3

Fragment3_***_*__*_*___**_onCreate

Fragment3_***_*__*_*___**_onCreateView

Fragment3_***_*__*_*___**_add Fragment4

Fragment4_***_*__*_*___**_onCreate

Fragment4_***_*__*_*___**_onCreateView

Fragment4_***_*__*_*___**_add Fragment5

Fragment5_***_*__*_*___**_onCreate

Fragment5_***_*__*_*___**_onCreateView

***Fragment5*** __*_*__*_*_ ***replace Fragment6***

***Fragment1*** __*_*__*_*_ ***onDestroyView***

***Fragment3*** __*_*__*_*_ ***onDestroyView***

***Fragment5*** __*_*__*_*_ ***onDestroyView***

Fragment6_***_*__*_*___**_onCreate

Fragment6_***_*__*_*___**_onCreateView

---

My questions:

**Why** after the Fragment5 is **replaced** by Fragment6, the Fragment1 & 3 &5 are destroyed their view ?.

**What** is happending with Fragment2 & 4 ?

**Why** Fragment2 & 4 are not destroyed their view as Fragment1 & 3 &5 ?

Please help me to understand fully about fragment's lifecycle when call the add() and replace() method.

---

Update my addFragment and replaceFragment method:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fromFragment, Fragment toFragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container,toFragment, toFragment.getClass().getName());
    transaction.hide(fromFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(toFragment.getClass().getName());
    transaction.commit();
}

public void replaceFragment(Fragment fromFragment, Fragment toFragment) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container,toFragment, toFragment.getClass().getName());
    transaction.hide(fromFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(toFragment.getClass().getName());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the code for swapping out the fragments and the XML for the view where you're swapping out the fragments.

Answer (score 7):

If you use a `FragmentTransaction` to hide the fragment, then it can still be in the running state of its lifecycle, but its UI has been detached from the window so it's no longer visible. So you could technically still interact with the fragment and reattach its UI later you need to. If you replace the fragment, then you are actually pulling it out of the container and it will go through all of the teardown events in the lifecycle (`onPause`, `onStop`, etc) and if for some reason you need that fragment again you would have to insert it back into the container and let it run through all of its initialization again.

Answer (score 5):

When you replace, you're swapping out all of the fragments (1,2,3,4,5) in the `ViewGroup` `R.id.container` for your new `Fragment` (6). Once the fragments have been removed, they will be destroyed. When destroyed, they will call the `onDestroyView()` method.

[FragmentTransaction replace](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String))

With regards to your question for 2 and 4, I'm not sure. Are you able to post more of the code what writes out to logcat?

Comment: as i mentioned above: in each of method onCreate(), onCreateView(), onDestroyView(), onDestroy() of fragment i had a simple print-point to track it's lifecycle. Example: onCreate(){ Log.d(Tag, onCreate); }