# How to start Fragment from an Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I already want to start my RecipientFragment from my MainActivity and pass data onto the Fragment from my MainActivity. Here is the code that I have implemented. But the fragment does not start.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE_TYPE, fileType);
RecipientsFragment keyfile = new RecipientsFragment();
keyfile.setArguments(bundle);
Fragment newFragment = new RecipientsFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.commit();
```

I also want to know how to pass intent.setData and get that data in Fragment. Currently I have below code:

RecipientFragment

```
mMediaUri = getActivity().getIntent().getData();
```

MainActivity

```
Intent recipientsIntent = new Intent(this, RecipientsFragment.class);
        recipientsIntent.setData(mMediaUri);
```

Comment: But you didn't added code for adding or replacing the fragment anywhere?

Comment: Here is the official documentation on Fragments in android From the **Fragment life** cycle to **Implementation** of fragments https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can either add or replace fragment in your activity. Create a `FrameLayout` in activity layout `xml` file.

Then do this in your activity to **add** fragment:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

And to **replace** fragment do this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

See Android documentation on [adding a fragment to an activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Adding) or following related questions on SO:

[Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

[Basic difference between add() and replace() method of Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466302/basic-difference-between-add-and-replace-method-of-fragment)

[Difference between add() & replace() with Fragment's lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032113/difference-between-add-replace-with-fragments-lifecycle)

Comment: If you are using Android X, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead of `getFragmentManager`

Comment: You forgot to add that the FrameLayout in the XML file should have "container" set as the id.

Answer (score 17):

Simple way

1. Create a new java class

   ```
   public class ActivityName extends FragmentActivity {
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       if (savedInstanceState == null){
       getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
               .add(android.R.id.content, new Fragment_name_which_you_wantto_open()).commit();}
    }
   }
   ```
2. in your activity where u want to call fragment

   ```
    Intent i = new Intent(Currentactivityname.this,ActivityName.class);
    startActivity(i);
   ```

Another Method

1. Place frame layout in your activity where u want to open fragment

   ```
     <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       </FrameLayout>
   ```
2. Paste this code where u want to open fragment

   ```
       Fragment mFragment = null;
           mFragment = new Name_of_fragment_which_you_want_to_open();
           FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
           fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                   .replace(R.id.frameLayout, mFragment).commit();
   ```

Comment: I think we should also define that class name in manifest for first way

Comment: The actionbar is not visible for method 1 !!

Comment: @PrajwalW Maybe issue is in your theme, Please check carefully

Answer (score 8):

## Another ViewGroup:

A fragment is a ViewGroup which can be shown in an Activity. But it needs a Container. The container can be any Layout (FragmeLayout, LinearLayout, etc. It does not matter).

[image]

**Step 1:**

> Define Activity Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/fragmentHolder"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 2:**

> Define Fragment Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/user"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <EditText
       android:id="@+id/password"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    <Button
       android:id="@+id/login"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Login"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Step 3:**

> Create Fragment class

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {


    private Button login;
    private EditText username, password;

    public static LoginFragment getInstance(String username){
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putInt("USERNAME", username);
       LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
       fragment.setArguments(bundle);
       return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState){
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, parent, false);
       login = view.findViewById(R.id.login);
       username = view.findViewById(R.id.user);
       password = view.findViewById(R.id.password);
       String name = getArguments().getInt("USERNAME");
       username.setText(username);
       return view;
    }

}
```

**Step 4:**

> Add fragment in Activity

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity{

   private Fragment currentFragment;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       currentFragment = LoginFragment.getInstance("Rohit");
       getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentHolder, currentFragment, "LOGIN_TAG")
                .commit();
   }

}
```

### Demo Project:

This is code is very basic. If you want to learn more advanced topics in Fragment then you can check out these resources:

[Woof - Learn the fragment right way](https://github.com/rohitksingh/Woof)
[My Android Garage](https://github.com/rohitksingh/My_Android_Garage/tree/master/Fragment%20Related%20Stuff)

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you start Activities and Services with an intent, you start fragments with fragment transactions.
Secondly, your transaction isnt doing anything. 
Change it to something like:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager();
    transaction.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.layout.container, newFragment) //<---replace a view in your layout (id: container) with the newFragment 
        .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this, it is best to design fragment construct to receive that data and save that data in its bundle arguments.

```
   class FragmentA extends Fragment{
    public static FragmentA newInstance(YourDataClass data) {

            FragmentA f = new FragmentA();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("data", data);
            f.setArguments(b);

            return f;
        }
    }
```

In order to start the fragment from the class, you can do the following

```
 Fragment newFragment = FragmentA.newInstance(objectofyourclassdata);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

However, the data class must be parceable or serializable.

For full information on fragments and best practices on use of fragments, please spend some time on official docs, it is super useful, at least my experience

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#java

Answer (score 0):

How to start fragment from Activity in Android Kotlin

Add Fragment:

```
val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
val transaction: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
transaction.add(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
```

Replace Fragment:

```
val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.container, YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME, YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
```

[Here is more on fragment manager: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager)

Answer (score 0):

for kotlin you can do that like

`val myFragment= WelcomeFragment()           supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_containerID,myFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit()`

Answer (score -4):

You Can Start Activity and attach **RecipientsFragment** on it , but you cant start Fragment