# Opening fragment

Tags: java, android

I am creating a quiz in my app and after the score has been shown it returns to an activity 'NavigActivity' however I am wondering how i would change this code to return to a fragment which is the second icon in my bottom navigation bar? the fragment I want it to return to is DashboardFragment

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your score: " + percentage + "%", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(EmotionsActivity.this, NavigActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}, 3000); // Set your time here //
```

Comment: See this post:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100187/how-to-start-fragment-from-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

Pass an extra from EmotionsActivity.java in the run() method:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(EmotionsActivity.this, NavigActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("unique_id", "from_emotions_activity"); 
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}, 3000); // Set your time here //
```

and in your `NavigActivity` `onCreate()` method:

```
String fromWhichActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("unique_id");
if (fromWhichActivity.equals("from_emotions_activity") {
    // perform fragmentTranaction...add/replace....commit
}
```