# Having problems to pass data from recyclerview adapter to fragment

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

So I am developing a project with view pager that has 2 tabs with 2 different fragments. There's a card view in both of the fragments. When I click on one of the item in the card view, it should go to another fragment to load the web view with URLs that are passed from the recycler view adapter. I tried to pass the URLs from the adapter to the fragment to load the web view but the app keep on crashing in the emulator. I might be using the wrong method for this or there's something I didn't include in the program. I really need help!

main_activty.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="CYBERSECURITY" />

            <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="AI" />
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/webView_Frame"
    tools:context=".FragmentWeb">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    </WebView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
 final String URLs = news.getURLs();
    Log.d("here",URLs);

    myViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString(KEY, URLs);
            FragmentWeb fragmentWeb = new FragmentWeb();
            fragmentWeb.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentWeb.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.webView_Frame, fragmentWeb)
                    .commit();
        }
    });
```

Above are the codes I tried to pass the URLs to the FragmentWeb class. I tried with log.d to check and the URLs variable already contain all the URLs. I've also tried with fragmentWeb.getChildFragmentManager or even fragmentWeb.getFragmentManager but neither of them work and keep giving me different errors.

FragmentWeb.java

```
public class FragmentWeb extends Fragment{

    private static final String KEY = "URLS";
    private String URLs;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private WebView webView;

    public FragmentWeb() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            URLs = getArguments().getString(KEY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web, container, false);
        progressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        webView = view.findViewById(R.id.web_view);
        return view;
    }

    public void loadWebPage()
    {
        webView.loadUrl(URLs);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String URLs, Bitmap favicon) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String URLs) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        loadWebPage();
    }
}
```

Above are the codes to load the web page with the URLs passed from the adapter.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.assignment4_task1, PID: 6803
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()' on a null object reference at com.example.assignment4_task1.MyRecyclerViewAdapter$1.onClick(MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java:66)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6294)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24770)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start Fragment from an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100187/how-to-start-fragment-from-an-activity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
    FragmentWeb fragmentWeb = new FragmentWeb();
    fragmentWeb.setArguments(bundle);
    fragmentWeb.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
```

You're calling 'getActivity()' on fragmentWeb, but you've just created fragmentWeb above. That fragment is not loaded in any activity yet, so getActivity() returns null.
Get the current activity from the surrounding context, such as the RecyclerView's context or, if you declare the Adapter as an inner class of your Fragment, by using Fragment's getActivity().

Comment: Do you mean like this?

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(KEY, URLs);
                FragmentWeb fragmentWeb = new FragmentWeb();
                fragmentWeb.setArguments(bundle);
                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.webView_Frame, fragmentWeb)
                        .commit();

Comment: Possibly, I don't know how you defined mContext, but if it is indeed the current activity, that should work.