# How to Intent From Activity to Fragment?

Tags: android

Hello Everyone, 
         On my main Activity, I have some menus.
What I want to do is that, if a user click on the menu, he/she must navigate, or must be landed on a Fragment.

I know from Activity to Activity is just pass an Intent eg: 
Intent intent New Intent (Activity1.this. Activity2.class);
And From Fragment to Activity eg:
Intent intent New Intent (getContext() Activity2.class);

But how to Intent from an Activity to a Fragment?  Or have to Navigate from An Activity to a Fragment?
Is that possible ?

Does anyone have an idea how to do that ?
thanks a lot.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100187/how-to-start-fragment-from-an-activity

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,
   Fragment fragment = new Fragment_class();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment).addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent is only used with Activities, Services, and BroadcastReceivers.
A fragment as its name suggests is part of an Activity that adds the dynamic content replacement to it.

Your options:

1. A parent activity with two fragments that get replaced dynamically
2. Two Activities that each have a fragment inside.
3. Using Android Navigation Component which handles most of the transactions.

When Working with fragments you have two options:

1. Using Static Fragments

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.example.myapp.FragmentA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

2. Dynamic fragment replacement

Inside Activity's XML

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Inside Activity's Java File:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frameLayout, SecondFragment());
transaction.commit();
```

You can also use this component as part of the android JetPack
[Android Navigation Component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)