# How to use setContentView in fragment instead of an activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, setcontentview

Dear Stackoverflowers :)

`AllAssetsFragment` is opened from the MainActivity. In this fragment, I have trouble setting up the `setContentView()` and `getApplicationContext()` properly.

I know there is something wrong. Some of the code works for normal activities but they are not working in this fragment.

AllAssetsFragment:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.room.Room;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class AllAssetsFragment extends Fragment {

    public AllAssetsFragment(){


    }


    private static final String HI = "https://uniqueandrocode.000webhostapp.com/hiren/favouritelist.php";
    private List<AssetsItem>assetsItems;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    AssetsAdapter adapter;

    private JsonArrayRequest request;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    public static FavoritesDatabase favoritesDatabase;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allassets, container, false);


        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // +++ PROBLEM 1: Context doesn't work (same on Problem 3 and 4) +++
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        assetsItems = new ArrayList<>();
        btn=(Button)getView().findViewById(R.id.favbtn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // +++ PROBLEM 2: This code doesn't work to open Fragment from Fragment +++
                startActivity(new Intent(AllAssetsFragment.this, FavoritesFragment.class));
            }


        });
        favoritesDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), FavoritesDatabase.class, "myfavdb").allowMainThreadQueries().build();
        getData();

    }

    private void getData() {
        request = new JsonArrayRequest(HI, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject ob = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        AssetsItem pr = new AssetsItem(ob.getInt("id"),
                                ob.getString("product_name"),
                                ob.getString("product_img"));
                        assetsItems.add(pr);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                setupData(assetsItems);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        // +++ PROBLEM 3: Context doesn't work +++
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private void setupData(List<AssetsItem>assetsItems){
    adapter=new AssetsAdapter(assetsItems,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And here our 2nd Fragment: FavoritesFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {


    public FavoritesFragment() {

    }

    private RecyclerView rv;
    private FavoritesAdapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false);

        rv=(RecyclerView)getView().findViewById(R.id.rec);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        // +++ PROBLEM 4: doesn't work +++
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        getFavData();
    }

    private void getFavData(){
        List<FavoritesItem>favoritesItems=AllAssetsFragment.favoritesDatabase.favoritesDao().getFavoritesData();

        adapter = new FavoritesAdapter(favoritesItems,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }



}
```

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the mistakes you made in your code.

#### AllAssetsFragment

- Move the line below to the bottom of the `onCreateView()` method. It is a return statement, therefore, it has to be the last thing in the function.

  ```
  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allassets, container, false);
  ```
- You can't use `startActivity(...)` to launch a fragment. This method is strictly for launching activities. To learn how to launch a fragment, check [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36100397/5670752) out.
- Replace `this` with `getActivity()` in the lines below:

  `recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`
  `requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);`

#### FavoritesFragment

- Replace `this` with `getActivity()` in the line below:

  `rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

**Addendum:**

To launch a fragment within an activity (in your case, MainActivity), follow the following steps:

1. In your **activity_main.xml** file, create a FrameLayout that would house your fragment, you can give it an id: `container`. If you don't know how to do this, just paste the code below:

   ```
   <FrameLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/container" />
   ```
2. When you want to launch a fragment from an activity, simply use this code snippet:

   ```
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.container, new AllAssetsFragment());
   transaction.commit();
   ```
3. When you want to launch a fragment from another fragment, simply use this code snippet:

   ```
   FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
   transaction.replace(R.id.container, new AllAssetsFragment());
   transaction.commit();
   ```
4. In the code snippets above, if `getFragmentManager()` does not work or if you are using AndroidX, use `getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

Comment: All other suggestions worked well! 
But I have no clue how I can get `AllAssetsFragment` and `FavoritesFragment` classes launched. 
Important to know: They are already made with the name in the code down below.
Only this line is wrong, can you write a working one for me? ;) Thanks!

`startActivity(getActivity(AllAssetsFragment, FavoritesFragment.class));`

Comment: I have updated my answer. I added a few steps on how to launch fragments.

Comment: If there's anything you're stuck on, let me know. I'll explain.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `setContentView()` within fragments. You should init your view in `onCreateView()`, like you already do.

About application context, I see that you are passing it to your adapter. I would argue that you don't need the application context there, as the context of the fragment should be enough. You can pass `requireContext()`.

You will also need to setup your `RecyclerView` and adapter from `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I added it in the code above, but still have 3 problems with context and 1 with opening the fragment from the existing fragment. To make it more easier I added to code above with the 2nd fragment. Would be great if you can solve those problems! :)

Comment: @Lulu96 I agree with Minas Mina. Recently Android Studio's lint recommends to use `requireContext` to get a Context. Try to replace `getActivity().getApplicationContext()` or `this` with `requireContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call `setContentView` in fragments you need return view in `onCreateView` method. you have already done.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_allassets, container, false);
}
```

and for `getApplicationContext` you need to call `getActivity()`

like this

`getActivity().getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I added it in the code above, but still have 3 problems with context and 1 with opening the fragment from the existing fragment.