# How to declare Fragment in Android Manifest

Tags: android

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.riddhi.nfine/com.riddhi.nfine.EMI.Ui.main.EmiFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1932)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:662)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
    at com.riddhi.nfine.EMI.Ui.create.DateActivity$onCreate$7.onClick(DateActivity.kt:232)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:967)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

I have a fragment in which i have added activity,through a button

Here's the code for DateActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_date)
    ....
   
        val intent = Intent(this, EmiFragment::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        val showContent = Intent(
            applicationContext,
            EmiFragment::class.java
        )
        startActivity(showContent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

There's an error in `startActivity(showContent)`, Can someone please help me on how to solve it?

Comment: You can't start Fragment like Activity. The fragment is hosted inside of Activity in FrameLayout or Fragment View group. then you can change or replace many fragments using `FragmentManager ` Please check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100187/how-to-start-fragment-from-an-activity)

Comment: You need to define the `activity` in your manifest file, not `fragment`. Define the name of the `activity` which contains your `fragment`

Comment: I would recommend you to read: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments

Comment: I followed the same procedure but even then error persists