# How to change the current fragment view with other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to change the whole view of a fragment with other fragment !!

Or how to close the current fragment with another fragment, please explain with layout also

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Google it first, there are n number of tutorials.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't even bother to make a minimal research on Google.

Answer (score 0):

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentlayout,new fragment()).commit()
```

This will help you replace your existing fragment in view with id FragmentLayout with a `new fragment()`.

ThankYou i hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add or replace fragments in your activity. Create a `FrameLayout` in activity's layout `xml` file.

Then do this in your activity to **replace** fragment. You can use same code each time you want to replace one fragment with other.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

If you want to **add** fragment instead of replace then do this:

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.container,YOUR_FRAGMENT_NAME,YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

When you want to replace added frogment with anu other fragment then you have to **remove** previous fragment first (or you can **hide** previous fragment; depends on your requirement). See following code:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(YOUR_FRAGMENT_STRING_TAG);
if(fragment != null)
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(fragment).commit();
```

See following related questions on SO:

[Difference between add(), replace(), and addToBackStack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634207/difference-between-add-replace-and-addtobackstack)

[Basic difference between add() and replace() method of Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466302/basic-difference-between-add-and-replace-method-of-fragment)

[Difference between add() & replace() with Fragment's lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20032113/difference-between-add-replace-with-fragments-lifecycle)

Or see my answer to a similar question:

[How to start Fragment from an Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36100187/how-to-start-fragment-from-an-activity/36100397#36100397)

Answer (score 0):

First you take one Framelayout in Your Activity where you add fragment.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.framelayout,fragment_1);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

When you replace first fragment with second one you write, just change fragment_1 to fragment_2

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.framelayout,fragment_2);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```